# conditional product tabs

Tags: frontend, tabs, local.xml

My client wants to have a different set of tabs for products belonging to category B.  I added code below to Custom Layout settings.

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/view-wfc.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

It works so I can change the position of the tabs and put them above the add to cart blocks.  But no matter what I do to local.xml the tabs stay the same for all products.

Here is what I have tried:
in local.xml I added this -

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.btabs" as="b_tabs">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                <alias>description_tabbed</alias>
                <title>Details</title>
                <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
                <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                <alias>additional_tabbed</alias>
                <title>Description</title>
                <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
                <template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>product_tag_list</name>
        </action>
        <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                <alias>description_tabbed</alias>
                <title>Description</title>
                <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
                <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                <alias>additional_tabbed</alias>
                <title>Additional</title>
                <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
                <template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

in view-wfc.html I added this -

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml( 'b_tabs' ); ?>
```

Basically I want products in Category B to have tabs labeled "Details" and "Description" and to be in that order.  In products belong to any category besides category B I want their tabs labeled "Description" and "Additional" and to be in that order.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On product pages, if you visit them via a category, the product will have an active category. With that you should be able to make an if/else for the tabs.

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if (!is_null($category)) {
   if ($category->getId() == X) { // id of category B
      echo $this->getChildHtml( 'b_tabs' );
   } else {
      echo $this->getChildHtml( 'info_tabs' );
   }
}
```

Comment: That does help with the conditional part.  But the tabs are still the same.  It doesn't matter if I call 'b_tabs' or 'info_tabs' I only get 'info_tabs' set.  Can you please checkout the xml?

Comment: It might be because the `name` is the same. Instead of using `as` please try and change the `name` to `b_tabs` and `info_tabs`